# Using cin>>"(variable created)"; as the pause option

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I tried to work out the system pause using various techniques. I finally got an option of `cin>> "(variable created)";` to make the program wait for my command to close. It works ok. 
Now, the question is that is it ok to follow that technique or does it leave loopholes, like `system("pause");`?

Comment: Just don't do this. Configure your environment properly to leave the shell open after your program terminates, if that's what you want. It is not your program's job to sit there doing nothing just because your shell is improperly configured for showing you the program's output.

Comment: If you are running inside an IDE there is usually an option to hold the IO window open after the application exits. Find this and turn it on. If you are running from a shell already then why do you want to pause the application before exit?

Answer (score 3):

A breakpoint is the best way to pause the program. These are actually intended for pausing programs.

Comment: not to be a pain, but what is a breakpoint and how to use it?
and i tried using 
char dummy[2];
cin.getline(dummy, 2);
and it doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

`cin>> "(variable created)"` is an extremely lousy way to pause your program - if the user enters anything, you're invoking undefined behavior by trying to overwrite a read-only string (which actually makes your program segfault on some systems).

You could use

```
char dummy[2];
cin.getline(dummy, 2);
```

if you don't care about the state of the input stream afterwards (some input will be left there, failbit may be set).

Generally, I would advise against using pauses at the end of program of any sort.

Comment: Does `std::cin >> "(variable created)"` actually compile with turboc++?! It certainly doesn't with g++. I'm pretty sure, the OP means something like `std::string dummy; std::cin >> dummy;`

Comment: but not using pauses only end up with programs closing instantly. thats why i had to use this command...wont creating a random variable like int d; and using that variable to pause the program ,cin>>d;

Comment: @stefan
in turbo c++, std is not recognized.. i have to avoid using that command and write the remaining cin..... directly

Comment: @user1951597 what the ****? `std::cin` should be recognized, `cin` shouldn't (unless you use `using namespace std;` or `using std::cin;`). Did you `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: yes sir
i start like this....
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{.....}
i firsted using using namespace std
bt it doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

After using cin.getline(...) use cin.flush(). This command remove newline from buffer.